# Doing maths with distance values in LaTeX source code

Tags: macros, calculations

I have a `sty` file with the command

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\noindent\kern#1}
```

but I'd actually like to have something like

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\noindent\kern{#1 *0.5}}
```

meaning that I'd like to have half of the distance the user puts on command `\foo` to be passed to `\kern`. This obviously doesn't work.

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this?

(You may ask "why the hell would you want to do that??". Fair question. I'm using someone else's program which generates tex files and I don't have control over the values that come up on the command `\foo`. I just know that I'd like to have half of what that program chooses.)

Comment: This is a question for the experts on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the eTeX primitive `\dimexpr` to allow a factor like before dimension registers:

```
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\noindent\kern .5\dimexpr#1\relax}
```

Note that `\dimexpr` swallows the `\relax` and also allows for some arithmetic inside. See the [etex_man](http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/etex/base/etex_man.pdf)ual for more details.

Comment: @Martin: Please slow down -- I've got only one vote left for today. :-)

Comment: +1 for teaching me that `\dimexpr` can optionally swallow a `\relax`. Yesterday I tried to use `\relax` as a delimiter for `\numexpr`, and I just couldn't understand why the `\relax` is gone although it's not expandable.

Comment: @Hendrik: Yeah, I think you need two `\relax` then. I find the `\relax` swallowing extremely useful. Its friends like `\numexpr` do the same.

Comment: It's funny that the short and simple answers (simple for someone who happens to know that stuff) give you often the most up-votes and badges (just got "Nice Answer" and "Enlightened" for this four lines).

Comment: @Martin: That's when the SE model is working at its best.  Something you just _happen_ to know is exactly what someone else wants to know!

Comment: @Hendrik: You say "optionally".  Martin didn't have that word.  That makes it sound as though there's a choice as to whether the `\relax` is swallowed or not.

Comment: @Andrew: I say "optionally" since there needn't be any swallowable `\relax` delimiting the `\dimexpr`. (Is "swallowable" an English word?)

Comment: @Hendrik: Ah, so it is the `\relax` that is optional, not the swallowabilitiness (anything you can do ...).  A better phrasing would be "will swallow an optional `\relax`".

Comment: @Andrew: Yep, that phrasing is a lot less misleading. Now make a moderator edit my comment `:-)`

Answer (score 14):

Multiplication of dimensions is built into TeX.  So you can do this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
    \dimen@ #1
    \kern 0.5\dimen@%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

a\foo{72pt}b

a\kern 72pt b

\end{document}
```

`\dimen@` is a dimension register that is by convention for temporary use. The macro `\foo` saves `#1` in this register and then kerns by half of it.

Comment: The LaTeX kernel also uses `\@tempdima` to `\@tempdimc` as temporary dimension registers.

Comment: and you can create your own with `\newdimen\mydimen`.

Comment: @Norman: Thanks for that; I hadn't known that there were others.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the low-level support described in other answers, you might find the [calc package](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/calc.pdf) useful, depending on exactly what it is you want to do.