# Resizing a table by textheight

Tags: tables, scaling

Say, I have a table which doesn't fit on one page. Say, I don't want to use any special table types or so but want to solve the problem by using the `\resizebox`-command and keep my ratio.

If by using `\resizebox{\texwidth}{!}{...}` the table fits, then my problem is solved. But if the table is still too long, my instinct would be to use `\resizebox{!}{\textheight}{...}` instead. Allowing some space for my caption I would have to adjust the height to about `0.9\textheight` to be sure for a single line caption. But in my example I have ta adjust to approx. `0.48\textheight` to get rid of all warnings and fit the table on the page. This seems very odd to me. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
%   \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \resizebox{!}{0.48\textheight}{
        \begin{tabular}{|lll|}\hline
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\
            TextTextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText & TextTextTextTextText\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}}
    \caption{test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are running into the common problem of confusing the *height* and the *totalheight* of things in TeX. For some reason which also surprised me the baseline of the table is the the middle of the table, so that the lower half is part of the *depth* of the resulting TeX box. The `\resizebox` scales the box *height*, not the *totalheight* (height+depth) to the given value.
To scale the totalheight use the `*` version. You can also use `\dimexpr` (see also [Doing maths with distance values in LaTeX source code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11346/doing-maths-with-distance-values-in-latex-source-code/11347#11347)) or the `calc` package to subtract e.g. two lines from the height:

```
\resizebox*{!}{\dimexpr\textheight-2\baselineskip\relax}{%
```

Also note that placing a large table in a macro argument is very inefficient and doesn't allow the usage of `\verb` etc. in the table. You can use the `\adjustbox` macro or `adjustbox` environment from the relative new `adjustbox` package (written by me) to scale any content instead. Both read the content as box not as argument and avoid the mentioned drawbacks:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% [...]

\begin{adjustbox}{totalheight=\textheight-2\baselineskip}
  \begin{tabular}{...}
     ...
  \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
```

The `adjustbox` environment and macro accepts all options of the `\includegraphics` macro. This includes `height` and `totalheight`.

Note that `adjustbox` uses `pgfmath` to parse the given dimensions, so you can use all math supported by this package. However do not use `\dimexpr` directly because it [isn't supported by `pgfmath`](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3165954&group_id=142562&atid=752792).

Comment: I fixed the previously mentioned issue with identical output for `height` and `totalheight` now and uploaded the correct version as 2011/03/20 v0.3 to CTAN. However, simply using `totalheight` as shown now works also with the previous version.

Comment: The baseline of the `tabular` is in the middle as the default position argument is `[c]`, if you use `t` or `b` then the baseline is the baseline of the top or bottom row (or rule).

Comment: using `\resizebox*{!}{\dimexpr\textheight-2\baselineskip\relax}{%` didn't work in my case in `beamer`, the table was vertically still too large. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ghx: the body area of `beamer` is smaller than `\textheight` so far I remember as some space is used for the headline. You should search for a better dimension provided by `beamer`.