# Applying breqn in bulk to typeset a math book for my kindle?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, breqn, ebook

I'm trying to typeset this book for my Kindle: http://linear.ups.edu/

Unfortunately some of the equations result in overfull hboxes, and I can't read them.

Though I've managed to manually convert some of the examples, the process is very difficult. The tricky bits primarily involve removing alignment markers from amsmath `align` environments, and nesting each sub-equation in its own `\begin{dmath*}`... For example:

```
\begin{align*}
2x+3y-4z&=13
&
4x_1+5x_2-x_3+x_4+x_5&=0
&
9a-2b+7c+2d&=-7
\end{align*}
```

(I've not even begun trying to figure out tables, so automatically scaling those would also be nice!)

Perhaps there is a simple way to automatically wrap or scale all equasions/tables? I'm not so concerned with them looking that good yet, my first priority is being able to see them...

I based my approach on [LaTeX options for kindle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16735/latex-options-for-kindle) but this type of conversion is too much even with liberal application of Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the size, so that it fits to the page, you can use the [adjustbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package, see also [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13809/resizing-a-table-by-textheight/13812#13812):

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}

...

\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
  \begin{table}{...}
     ...
  \end{table}
\end{adjustbox}
```

(Works also for figures and everything else.) This might result in a very small font size.

Answer (score 2):

The answers to [this TeX.SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1632/creating-kindle-friendly-versions-of-existing-latex-documents) describe the difficulty of your question. (Unfortunately, TeX is unwilling to see an overfull hbox and fix it for you.)

As noted in section 6 of [this document](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/technote.pdf), changing the `align*` environment is messy and difficult. You mention Perl—have you tried writing a script to scan the TeX source and delete each instance of `&` or `\\` between `\begin{align*}` and `\end{align*}` and then change each `align*` to `breqn`? Any sort of useful solution to your problem will have to involve mass automated editing of this sort.