# How could I use scalebox to rescale a table such that it fits exactly in the usable page width (i.e., between the margins)?

Tags: tables, boxes, scaling, width

How could I use scalebox to rescale a table such that it fits exactly in the usable page width (i.e., between the margins)? Is there some way in which something such as `\hsize` could be used as an argument for \scalebox?

Comment: Use `\resizebox` rather than `\scalebox`

Comment: If your need to fit into two dimensions (i.e., width and height should be maximized keeping the aspect ratio, but not exceed the available space), I suggest  the `adjustbox` package, with provides all this in via a very comfortable interface.

Comment: See if this thread helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13809/27635

Comment: But scaling tables produces inconsistent font sizes and should be a method of last resort.

Comment: The package ```adjustbox``` seems to work for what I'm trying to do. In the table environment, I am initialising the adjustbox environment, which subsequently acts on the tabular environment. The initialisation command for the adjustbox environment is as follows: \begin{adjustbox}{width=\hsize, totalheight=\textheight, keepaspectratio} Given the sheer volume of text in the table, there is no obvious way to contain the table in the page without blunt rescaling of the whole thing, including the text. Thanks for all suggestions!