# Add two lengths in raisebox argument, without the calc package

Tags: calculations, lengths

I've seen people use such constructs as `\raisebox{-\height+\baselineskip}{...}`, which works well using the `calc`package.

What equivalent would you use to achieve the same behaviour without the `calc` package?

Comment: You can also use `\adjustbox{raise=-\height+\baselineskip}{...}` from the `adjustbox` package. It uses e-TeX's `\dimexpr` by default, but also accepts the `calc` option to use the `calc` package. However, if your intention is to reduce the amount of packages used than this is of course a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: Related: [Doing maths with distance values in LaTeX source code](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11346/doing-maths-with-distance-values-in-latex-source-code)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\raisebox{\dimexpr -\height+\baselineskip\relax}{...}
```

works with etex which should be the default off all TeX engines

Answer (score 15):

You can use etex `\dimexpr`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
Test \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\baselineskip\relax}{Test} Test
\end{document}
```

[image]